# AbstractMethodError on Node.getTextContent()

Tags: java

Below is the sample code block throwing `AbstractMethodError`:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
..
Node root = soapBody.getElementByTagNameNS("http://xxx.xxx/Schema/v9", "Result").item(0); //Namespace
for (int i = 0; i < root.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {
 Node child = root.getChildNodes().item(i); //Set to SubResult
 String result = child.getTextContent(); //Throws error
}
```

The sample soap response :

```
soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><a1:Response xmlns:a1="http://xxx.xxx/Schema/v9"><a1:SubResult>50</<a1:SubResult></a1:Response></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Error thrown:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement.getTextContent()Ljava/lang/String;
```

Java version used : 1.5

Tomcat Version - 6.0.41

Checked [org.w3c.dom.Node for 1.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) and it does have the method getTextContent()

What could be the possible reason for this error?
Also, why does this appear : `org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement` instead of `org.w3c.Node`?

Answer (score 1):

The [javadoc of the AbstractMethodError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html) says:

> Thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method. Normally,
>   this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run
>   time if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since
>   the currently executing method was last compiled.

So it looks like you have some incompatible versions of something in your classpath.

`org.apache.axis.message.MessageElement` is part of Axis and should implement `org.w3c.dom.Node` so the versions of those two don't seem to match. Make sure you have matching versions of the two in your classpath.

Comment: Thanks @Jens! I'm a bit confused. The actual code has not just `getTextContent()` but also have other functions like : `getChildNodes()`, `hasChildNodes()`, `getNodeName()` which work fine! Also, when you say the versions do not match, Which jar's versions are you referring to?

Comment: the jars, which contain the classes/interfaces

Comment: There's just one of them which contains org.w3c.dom.Node. However, like I had mentioned earlier, `getTextNode()` is the only one that does not work and Java 1.5 has this method in place.

Comment: Sure, it is part of the interface. But the implementation comes from Axis and the version you have probably does not implement that method (because it is based on an older version)